# Shortest path in a complete weighted undirected graph with a known start node and visiting all nodes without returning to start node

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a complete undirected graph of locations (nodes), where each edge represents the distance between its connected nodes, and I want to find the shortest path starting from a start node without specifying the end node so basically it can end at any node other then the first one.

I looked through TSP problem and shortest Hamiltonian path but I couldn't find the exact response to my problem .

So what this problem is exactly called or what variant of shortest path problems it is?

This is an exemple of what I am looking for. Lets have a complete weighted graph as follows:[image: graph of locations]

Each edge represents the distance between two locations for exemple edge AB=5, AC=11......

My goal is to start from node A, and find the shortest path that covers all nodes (shortest possible path) and the end point can be any one other than A. For exemple this path that ends at E:
[image: shortest path]

Comment: Are you looking for a [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)?

Comment: The minimum spanning tree doesn't give a path, it covers the minimum possible total edge weight, which may not be a path in some cases. What I am looking for is a path that starts from a given node and ends at any other one . Let's say I am a traveler and I want to visit N countries starting from my home. My goal is to visit every country just one time and I will stay at the final country that I will visit (so the final country doesn't have to be specified from the beginning)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example graph (which is not too small so the solution isn't trivial), the result path you want to get and explain why that path is the correct path you are looking for and why it is not any other possible paths.

Comment: I added an exemple that may explain the problem. The shortest path have the shortest distance covering all nodes and starting from node A.

Comment: It looks like this is called "Shortest Hamiltonian Path".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a slight variation of a special case of [The Traveling Salesman Path Problem](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~alantha/papers2/tspath.pdf). In The Traveling Salesman Path Problem, you're given an undirected graph, a cost function on the edges, and two vertices `s` and `t`. The problem is to find a [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) (that is, a path that visits each vertex exactly once) from `s` to `t`.

Your problem is the special case in which the input graph is a [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) and the destination vertex `t` is an extra dummy vertex, connected to all other vertices by a 0-cost edge. Clearly, a solution to The Traveling Salesman Path Problem for the graph (with the extra dummy vertex `t`) induces a solution to your problem, obtained by simply ignoring the final extra step to the destination `t`.

Unfortunately, just like the famous [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), The Traveling Salesman Path Problem is not only NP-hard, but also NP-hard to approximate to within any constant factor. However, since your costs represent distances, maybe you could assume that the cost function satisfies [The Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)?

If the cost function satisfies The Triangle Inequality, then there exists a recent [1.5-approximation algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.04131). If this recent algorithm is an overkill, you can implement one of two simpler algorithms that are nicely described in [lecture notes](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/notes/lecture19.pdf) by Professor Ryan O’Donnell from CMU, and settle for either a 2-approximation or a 5/3-approximation.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for I'll search deeper to understand more the problem. Also I found that some people suggested the Branch & Bound algorithm for questions similar to this one so do you think it can be a possible solution?

Comment: @bessrourmalek, Yes, the Branch and Bound approach for solving TSP can be adapted to solving your problem exactly. Depending on the size of your graph, Branch And Bound techniques might work very well. However, this approach could be too computationally demanding if the input graph is massive or if it has some pathological properties that potentially degenerate the Branch and Bound approach to an exhaustive search. So yes, Branch and Bound may be a good heuristic approach to try as well, but without any guarantees.

Comment: Thank you for these detailed information I'll work on all these approaches to find the best algorithm that suits my input